# gptsync showing blank GPT and MBR partition table

Tags: dual-boot

#### background

I have Lion 10.7 and Windows 7 64 bit (Boot Camp) installed on my Mac Mini.

They both boot fine. But when I tried to run Windows 7 from Parallel using existing Boot Camp, I encountered problem stating `PRL_ERR_DISK_FILE_OPEN_ERROR (0x80021014)`.

After some googling, I found it is caused by `GPT` and `MBR` misaligned and can be corrected by using `gptsync` tool of rEFIt.

I installed rEFIt in my Lion partition and Partition Inspector shows a report with `GPT` and `MBR` misaligned.

```
    Current GPT partition table:
     #      Start LBA      End LBA  Type
     1             40       409639  EFI System (FAT)
     2         409640    740644007  Mac OS X HFS+
     3      740644008    741913543  Mac OS X Boot
     4      741914624    976773119  Basic Data

    Current MBR partition table:
     # A    Start LBA      End LBA  Type
     1              1       409639  ee  EFI Protective
     2         409640    740644007  af  Mac OS X HFS+
     3      740644008    741913543  ab  Mac OS X Boot
     4 *    741914624    976771071  07  NTFS/HPFS
```

#### problem

The problem is when I boot Mac mini in rEFIt and run `gptsync` in shell it only shows

```
    Shell> gptsync
    Error: Not Found returned from gptsync.efi
    Current GPT partition table:
    Current GPT partition table:
```

So...

What was I doing wrong? And how could I sync GPT and MBR table with or without gptsync.

Update

I manage to run gptsync on Mac using enhanced gptsync from [here](http://www.insanelymac.com/forum/index.php?showtopic=177505). Now the problem changed to

```
Writing new MBR...
gptsync: Data write failed at position 0: Bad file descriptor
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I boot Fedora 13 Live CD and use terminal to do the following

```
su
gptsync /dev/sda
```

and my HDD has GPT and MBR synced!!

Now I can use parallel with existing (boot camp installed) Windows in my Mac mini.